$f: \mathbb D\to \mathbb D$, $f(0)=0, f'(0)>0$ Implies locally biholomorphic.
The problem is one of our assignments after having a lesson of Riemann mapping theorem and continuity at the boundary.
Problem. Suppose that $f: \mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ is holomorphic. If $f'(0)=a>0$ and $f(0)=0$, prove that $f$ is biholomorphic on $B\left(0,\frac{a}{1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)$.
I think the problem resembles the Koebe-Bieberbach theorem and Bloch theorem; however, when I attempted to apply the same idea to this problem, I failed. The main obstacle is that I cannot construct the "square form," i.e.$\frac{a}{1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}$. I am unsure how to prove the injectivity. Perhaps the following lemma would work (I am uncertain):
$|f'(z)-f'(0)|<|f'(a)|$, then $f$ is injective.
